# ExpandableListView collapses all group items every time I come back from another Activity

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I need someone to guide me to find a fault. When I receive a call or go to another activity, when i come back all the groups are collapsed. The system has not Destroyed the activity so I can not save and restore the state in the onRestoreInstanceState because the method is never called (the Activity is only paused and stopped, but is not destroyed).

The Activity extends ExpandableListActivity and the adapter I use is a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.

In which cases the expandable list is collapsed? I'm going crazzy and I can't find out a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is the lifecycle of my Activity
when the Activivy Starts the first time:
 **onCreate() -> onStart() -> onResume()**
 when I go to other Activity:
**onPause() -> onStop()**
 and when I come back:
 **onRestart -> onStart() -> onResume()**

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the expanded state always resets whenever the focus is lost and onCreate() is not called when it gets the focus again but onStart(). So my workaround for now is to manually store the IDs of all expanded items and expand them in onStart() again. I implemented a subclass of ExpandableListActivity to reuse the behavior.

```
public class PersistentExpandableListActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

private long[] expandedIds;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (this.expandedIds != null) {
        restoreExpandedState(expandedIds);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    expandedIds = getExpandedIds();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    this.expandedIds = getExpandedIds();
    outState.putLongArray("ExpandedIds", this.expandedIds);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    long[] expandedIds = state.getLongArray("ExpandedIds");
    if (expandedIds != null) {
        restoreExpandedState(expandedIds);
    }
}

private long[] getExpandedIds() {
    ExpandableListView list = getExpandableListView();
    ExpandableListAdapter adapter = getExpandableListAdapter();
    if (adapter != null) {
        int length = adapter.getGroupCount();
        ArrayList<Long> expandedIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for(int i=0; i < length; i++) {
            if(list.isGroupExpanded(i)) {
                expandedIds.add(adapter.getGroupId(i));
            }
        }
        return toLongArray(expandedIds);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private void restoreExpandedState(long[] expandedIds) {
    this.expandedIds = expandedIds;
    if (expandedIds != null) {
        ExpandableListView list = getExpandableListView();
        ExpandableListAdapter adapter = getExpandableListAdapter();
        if (adapter != null) {
            for (int i=0; i<adapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                long id = adapter.getGroupId(i);
                if (inArray(expandedIds, id)) list.expandGroup(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static boolean inArray(long[] array, long element) {
    for (long l : array) {
        if (l == element) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static long[] toLongArray(List<Long> list)  {
    long[] ret = new long[list.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Long e : list)  
        ret[i++] = e.longValue();
    return ret;
}
}
```

Maybe someone has a better solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You can save any state information by overriding onPause() and onResume() in your Activity.

You should be able to persist the selected item and then reselect the item when the Activity is resumed. You could also add this in onStop() and onStart().

If the Activity is only being paused/stopped however all of the `Views` should retain their state as they aren't being destroyed and recreated. Try adding more logging to each of the "big" lifecycle methods:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);

 protected void onStart();

 protected void onRestart();

 protected void onResume();

 protected void onPause();

 protected void onStop();

 protected void onDestroy();
```

Creating a logging activity which you extend from should be your first step when tracking down lifecycle inconsistencies.